# Cruise control: should deployment be in tasks or publishers?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I'm setting up a Cruise Control configuration for one project. I have an <msbuild> task under <tasks>. It seems that I have the option of putting my file deployment under either <tasks> or <publishers>.

Logically I would think it should reside under <publishers> but none of the examples I have seen online work this way.

Should deployment happen within in <tasks> or <publishers>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deployment task should be in the tasks section.

As deployment part is playing with a final package, **the build must succeed**.

The `publisher` section is executed whatever the build result is. If you want to deploy only if all tasks succeed, then write the deployment section **as the last task of the `tasks` section**.

So if a task fails, the deployment will not occur.

**EDIT:** from ccnet documentation:

> The `publishers` section is run after
>   the build completes (whether it passes
>   or fails). This is where you aggregate
>   and publish the build results.

and

> Historical Note Publishers and Tasks
>   were different objects in earlier
>   version of ccnet. Now they are
>   interchangeable, and can appear either
>   in the <prebuild> section, the <tasks>
>   section, or the <publishers> section
>   of the ccnet.config file depending on
>   whether they should be run before,
>   during or after the build.

reference : http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Task+And+Publisher+Blocks

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your answer. If you replace your angular brackets with &lt; and &gt; then I will be able to see what tags you're referring to.

Comment: You can do a conditional publisher, and deploy only if your build was successful. If you don't want your deployment task to break your build in case of fail then you should put it under the publishers section.

Comment: A failed deployment should lead to a failed build ... at least if there is a client behind the deployment !

Comment: @TridenT The first sentence - I assume you mean the tasks section?

Comment: @Aligma: Did I drink before writing my answer ?

Comment: I now have a process in place where I call a nAnt build file from the tasks section. This process is working successfully for development, staging and production environments on about 20 projects. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Aligma: Good, it's nice to have the final word about it ! thx for the feedback.

Answer (score 3):

It depends. Since CC.Net 1.5 tasks and publishers are quite the same, you can put your any task in the publishers section. The main difference is that, if a publisher fail, your project does not fail (at least it is not shown as failed in CCTray).

For "simple" deployment (for example, copying a dll to a server) I did it under the publishers because this deployment task does not impact the success of the build and it's not that much important if the deploy fails.

If the deployment is a important part of the build (website deployment for example), then I put it in the tasks section to be sure to be notified when it fails.

Comment: +1 for the explanation, while this is not what I was looking for it does answer the question and will be useful in future, thank you.